# Unable to add element to black screen in Avogadro

Tags: software-sources

When i open Avogadro spots of previous screen is printed. After clicking New many times a black screen comes but then i am unable to add any graphics on the black part of Avogadro. I am also new to Ubuntu and also Avogadro. So kindly help me out.

And yes, i was unable to find an useful tag while posting this question. So, i am sorry about choosing a random one.